# Laravel authorisation policy using breeze to show only users created objects

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-8

I have created a new project with Laravel (8.12) and I have set up breeze for authentication which works fine. I also have a model called `Patient` with the below definition.

I currently have 2/3 objectives that I want to achieve but I'm not sure how to go about them.

1. When a user is logged in they can only see patients they have created and not other users patients
2. Enable a user to 'share' there patients making them visible to either:

   1. All other users or
   2. specific users

I know that Laravel uses policies for authorisation but I'm not sure how to go about achieving the above.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Patient extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'firstName',
        'middleNames',
        'surname',
        'dob',
        'nhsNumber',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Sharing patients sounds like a [many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) between users and patients.

Comment: Ahh, I'd not thought of it like that